# how to change special node value for xml using xls

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Previous xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <cities>
    <city abbr="A">"NameA1"</city>
    <city abbr="B">"NameB1"</city>
    <city abbr="C">"NameC1"</city>
 </cities>
```

Updated xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <cities>
    <city abbr="A">"NameD1"</city>
    <city abbr="B">"NameB1"</city>
    <city abbr="C">"NameC1"</city>
 </cities>
```

Description:
I want to find out the node which attribute 'abbr' equals to "A" and change the value from "NameA1" to "NameD1". I am not familiar with the xsl. Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Previous xml 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <cities>
        <city abbr="A">"NameA1"</city>
        <city abbr="B">"NameB1"</city>
        <city abbr="C">"NameC1"</city>
     </cities>

Updated xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <cities>
        <city abbr="A">"NameD1"</city>
        <city abbr="B">"NameB1"</city>
        <city abbr="C">"NameC1"</city>
     </cities>

Comment: Edit your question and put the example there only ..

Answer (score 0):

You should start off by using the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy all existing nodes in your XML without change. Then, you just need to add a separate template, which will take priority over the identity template, where you can match the text node you wish to change.

```
<xsl:template match="city[@abbr='A']/text()">
  <xsl:text>NameD1</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Putting these together gives this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="city[@abbr='A']/text()">
    <xsl:text>"NameD1"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```